# How to get current git tag/branch/revision at browser?

Tags: git

I have a project which uses git. I have access to webserver via ssh and I can execute a command:

```
git log --decorate
```

and it will give me information about what is currently deployed on that server. But if somebody doesn't have such access, they should always ask me to check.

I'm thinking about solution which will generate file with dump of `git log --decorate` or any other command after each `git pull` or when I checkout any tag. And everybody will have access via url `{website}/current-version.html`.

I think I should use git hooks or there is an easier solution?
How I can implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the git log output then a post-receive hook is best.

If you want to show a potentially more user-friendly version number then I'd suggest either:-

- a `post-receive` hook showing the name of the tag of the currently released version (assuming you tag versions)
- putting current-version.html in your git repo so it'll get updated along with the `git pull`

Answer (score 1):

If your server is a clone of the git repo and you are using tags, then, **git describe** will use the latest tag and give an offset:

```
$ git describe --long
r1.0-2-gca93d0a
```

In the above, the last tag was **r1.0** and the **2** indicates that we are two commits past that tag, with the **g** (which stands for 'git') and the current hash **ca93d0a** following.

```
$ git log --oneline
ca93d0a Add info on testing.
949d558 Fixes to get wsdl2java working.
d0a02b1 Initial CXF.
```

As can be seen here, the tag **r1.0** points at the **d0a02b1** commit:

```
$ git show-ref --dereference r1.0 | tail -1
d0a02b1488154b052fed9d568f3823d15567ebb5 refs/tags/r1.0^{}
```